# Create a Logical AND with Tensorflow using a Deep Neural Network classifier

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to make a basic Tensorflow model to predict the output of a logical AND:

```
+---------+---------+--------+
| Input A | Input B | Output |
+---------+---------+--------+
|    0    |    0    |   0    |
|    0    |    1    |   0    |
|    1    |    0    |   0    |
|    1    |    1    |   1    |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

I know other estimators would be better for this specific task, but I am sticking to **DNNClassifier**, because I am going to need it on future projects. This is my code for training and predicting the outputs:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset
import seaborn as sns
import glob
import os

def input(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
    # Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
    features = {key: np.array(value) for key, value in dict(features).items()}

    # Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating.
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, targets))  # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    # Shuffle the data, if specified.
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(10000)

    # Return the next batch of data.
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels


def train_model(learning_rate, steps, batch_size, training_examples, training_targets, validation_examples, validation_targets):
    periods = 10

    steps_per_period = steps / periods
    training_input_fn = lambda: input(training_examples, training_targets, batch_size=batch_size)
    predict_training_input_fn = lambda: input(training_examples, training_targets, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
    predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: input(validation_examples, validation_targets, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

    tensorflow_features = set([tf.feature_column.numeric_column(my_feature) for my_feature in training_examples])
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(optimizer, 5.0)
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=tensorflow_features,
        n_classes=2,
        hidden_units=[1],
        optimizer=optimizer,
        activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
        config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1)
    )

    # Train the model, but do so inside a loop so that we can periodically assess
    # loss metrics.
    print("Training model...")
    print("LogLoss error (on validation data):")
    training_errors = []
    validation_errors = []
    # The model will be trained in 10 periods:
    for period in range(0, periods):
        # Train the model, starting from the prior state.
        classifier.train(
            input_fn=training_input_fn,
            steps=steps_per_period
        )

        # Take a break and compute probabilities.
        training_predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn))
        training_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in training_predictions])
        training_pred_class_id = np.array([item['class_ids'][0] for item in training_predictions])
        training_pred_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(training_pred_class_id, num_classes=2)

        validation_predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn))
        validation_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in validation_predictions])
        validation_pred_class_id = np.array([item['class_ids'][0] for item in validation_predictions])
        validation_pred_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(validation_pred_class_id, num_classes=2)

        # Compute training and validation errors.
        training_log_loss = metrics.log_loss(training_targets, training_pred_one_hot)
        validation_log_loss = metrics.log_loss(validation_targets, validation_pred_one_hot)
        # Occasionally print the current loss.
        print("  period %02d : %0.2f" % (period, validation_log_loss))
        # Add the loss metrics from this period to our list.
        training_errors.append(training_log_loss)
        validation_errors.append(validation_log_loss)
    print("Model training finished.")
    # Remove event files to save disk space.
    _ = map(os.remove, glob.glob(os.path.join(classifier.model_dir, 'events.out.tfevents*')))

    # Calculate final predictions (not probabilities, as above).
    final_predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
    final_predictions = np.array([item['class_ids'][0] for item in final_predictions])

    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(validation_targets, final_predictions)
    print("Final accuracy (on validation data): %0.2f" % accuracy)
    # Output a graph of loss metrics over periods.
    plt.ylabel("LogLoss")
    plt.xlabel("Periods")
    plt.title("LogLoss vs. Periods")
    plt.plot(training_errors, label="training")
    plt.plot(validation_errors, label="validation")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    # Plot the confusion matrix.
    cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(validation_targets, final_predictions)
    # Normalize the confusion matrix by row (i.e by the number of samples
    # in each class).
    cm_normalized = cm.astype("float") / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    ax = sns.heatmap(cm_normalized, cmap="bone_r")
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    plt.title("Confusion matrix")
    plt.ylabel("True label")
    plt.xlabel("Predicted label")
    plt.show()
```

To train and predict the output I just run the following:

```py
training_examples = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]], columns=['input_a', 'input_b'])
training_targets = pd.DataFrame([[0],[0],[0],[1]], columns=['output'])
validation_examples = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,0],[0,1],[0,0],[1,1]], columns=['input_a', 'input_b'])
validation_targets = pd.DataFrame([[0],[0],[1],[0],[0],[0],[1]], columns=['output'])

train_model(
  learning_rate=0.001,
  steps=10,
  batch_size=1,
  training_examples=training_examples,
  training_targets=training_targets,
  validation_examples=validation_examples,
  validation_targets=validation_targets,
)
```

After several times tweaking the hyperparameters and running the code I always get pretty bad accuracy and a clearly wrong confusion matrix:
[image]

Is there some Tensorflow expert who can bring light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working!

I have removed the **hidden_units**:

```py
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(optimizer, 5.0)
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=tensorflow_features,
    n_classes=2,
    hidden_units=[],
    optimizer=optimizer,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
    config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1)
)
```

and updated the hyperparameters as follows:

```py
classifier = train_model(
  learning_rate=1,
  steps=100,
  batch_size=1,
  training_examples=training_examples,
  training_targets=training_targets,
  validation_examples=validation_examples,
  validation_targets=validation_targets,
)
```

Final output:

```
Training model...
LogLoss error (on validation data):
  period 00 : 9.87
  period 01 : 0.00
  period 02 : 0.00
  period 03 : 0.00
  period 04 : 0.00
  period 05 : 0.00
  period 06 : 0.00
  period 07 : 0.00
  period 08 : 0.00
  period 09 : 0.00
Model training finished.
Final accuracy (on validation data): 100%
```

[image: Confusion matrix]

Answer (score 0):

Try sigmoid activation.

The classic example of single-neuron AND has a solution with sigmoid activation function but does not have a single-neuron solution with ReLU, there are no weights possible that would fit the function.

If you want to use ReLU, then you will need an extra layer and more neurons to get the behavior of this function.

Comment: Thanks @Peteris, I already tried ussing `activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid` within the **DNNClassifier**, but then I get all predicted labels equal to "1" (I have updated the question adding sigmoid activation)